# How can I find the relative velocity given a fixed observer and another who's moving and between two vehicles when they have bearing angles?

Tags: calculus, vectors, physics, kinematics

The problem is as follows:

> In a race track an orange car $A$ is moving to the north
>   ($\textrm{Y-axis}$) at a rate of $20\frac{m}{s}$ with respect to that a tv
>   cameraman who is at a point labeled $O_{1}$ in the ground.
>   Simultaneously another car (blue) $B$ is moving to the direction known
>   as $N53^{\circ}W$ at $25\frac{m}{s}$ with respect to that another
>   cameraman $O_{2}$. If the second cameraman $O_{2}$ is holding a camera
>   in a dolly moving to the same direction of the blue car $B$ and the
>   velocity $v_{o_{2}o_{1}}$ is $5.0\,\frac{m}{s}$. Find the velocity of the blue
>   car $B$ with respect to that $A$ in $\frac{m}{s}$.

The given alternatives on my book are:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&-15\hat{i}+4\hat{j}\frac{m}{s}\\
2.&-24\hat{i}-2\hat{j}\frac{m}{s}\\
3.&-15\hat{i}-2\hat{j}\frac{m}{s}\\
4.&+26\hat{i}+2\hat{j}\frac{m}{s}\\
5.&-26\hat{i}+4\hat{j}\frac{m}{s}\\
\end{array}$

Okay I'm lost with this problem. Essentially my source of confusion is **how** should I understand

$v_{o_{2}o_{1}}= 5.0\,\frac{m}{s}$

My only guess here is that what the author intended to explain was that the velocity of the blue car with respect to that the first cameraman is $5\frac{m}{s}$. But other than that. I don't know exactly what else should I do with the given information to work with the given bearing angles.

Can somebody help me here?.

Answer (score 1):

I'll be honest, I don't think very highly of the way this question was posed to you.
It seems unnecessarily disorganized and confusing.

But we have a sentence starting with, "If the second cameraman $O_2$ is holding a camera in a dolly", followed by a direction and a "velocity" which is actually a speed (specifically, $5.0 \frac{\mathrm m}{\mathrm s}$), it seems the only thing this can be describing is the speed and direction of travel of the dolly.
"The same direction of the blue car $B$" is just a convoluted way of saying the direction is $N53^\circ W.$

One of the puzzling things about this problem statement is why use so many words to establish cameraman $O_1$ as a reference point and then not mention in words that the cameraman is the reference point with respect to which  the velocity of the dolly was described. Instead we are left to guess this because the two subscripts of $v_{O_2O_1}$ are the identifiers of the two cameramen, $O_1$ and $O_2$;
or perhaps because no reference point was named, we are supposed to interpret the
$5.0 \frac{\mathrm m}{\mathrm s}$ as a speed relative to the ground,
which makes it also a speed relative to $O_1$ (who doesn't move relative to the ground).

In any case, you have $O_2$ moving at $5.0 \frac{\mathrm m}{\mathrm s}$ in the direction $N53^\circ W$ relative to $O_1$ (or, equivalently, relative to the ground),
you have a blue car $B$ moving  $25.0 \frac{\mathrm m}{\mathrm s}$ in the direction $N53^\circ W$ relative to $O_2$,
and you have an orange car $A$ moving north at $20.0 \frac{\mathrm m}{\mathrm s}$
relative to $O_1.$

---

Once you decide what each velocity vector is and what it signifies (what is moving at that velocity relative to what), everything is just vector addition and subtraction with a few rules. In the following, I use letters $v$ and $w$ to denote velocities (i.e., each letter stands for a speed *and* direction):

- If D is moving at velocity $v$ relative to C, then C is moving at velocity $-v$ relative to D.
- If D is moving at velocity $v$ relative to C and E is moving at velocity $w$ relative to D, then E is moving at velocity $v+w$ relative to C.
- If C is moving at velocity $v$ relative to D and E is moving at velocity $w$ relative to D, then E is moving at velocity $w-v$ relative to C.

You can derive the third rule from the first two, but I still like to keep it in mind so that it is readily available to me.

Of course to actually add or subtract any of the vectors in the problem, I would convert each of the vectors to $\hat\imath$ and $\hat\jmath$ components.
A picture often helps, because then for oblique directions like 
$N53^\circ W$ you can draw a right triangle with the legs parallel to the axes and the vector on the hypotenuse.

Comment: When I was looking at this problem I also noticed some of your doubts, and my intuition let me guess that what whoever posed this problem intended to mean that the $v_{o_{2}o_{1}}$ is the velocity of the cameraman with respect to that the first as you indicated. I'm still confused as I don't know which sort of answer would yield from these assumptions.

Comment: The "sort of answer" you get is an expression with $\imath$ and $\jmath$ like you see in the alternatives given in the book. Getting it is a matter of applying vector operations as much as you need in order to figure out who's moving how relative to whom. There are only four objects to look at so there are only 12 such relationships, you already have three of them, and if you just keep applying the rules you'll eventually compare B with A. I'm sure you can solve it without working out _every_ other relationship first--and when I say "you" here I mean you personally, you can do it.

Comment: After doing all the procedures you mentioned I arrived to the second alternative as the answer. As you pointed out it helps much to make a drawing because this is key to make the subtraction of vectors finally between $v_{b}-v_{a}$. Because v$_{b}$ has coordinates as indicated $N53^{\circ}W$ such the subtraction cannot be done directly as between $v_{b}$ to the second cameraman which shares the same orientation as $v_{b}$ the blue vehicle. By the way doing a table can also help, I didn't used one but I found that using tables can assist greatly in ordering the information.

Comment: There _are_ a lot of different moving parts (literally) in this problem, and anything that helps you organize the information, like a table, is a good tool. Even just writing things out systematically is good, even if it isn't literally in a table.